# Is it possible to configure SSIS logging from a dtsConfig file?

Tags: ssis

I want to configure what events (and what attributes) are logged upon execution of a DTSX package for about 50 packages that we have. We're already using a .dtsConfig file to configure details of database connections and other properties. When I check the Log provider tree in the configuration wizard it only stores which connection to use for logging. Is it possible to store also the details? This is the configuration in the package:

```
<DTS:LoggingOptions>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="LoggingMode">1</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="FilterKind">0</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="EventFilter" DTS:DataType="8">3,7,OnError,13,OnInformation,9,OnWarning</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ColumnFilter" DTS:EventName="OnError">
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Computer">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Operator">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="SourceName">-1</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="SourceID">-1</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ExecutionID">-1</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="MessageText">-1</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DataBytes">-1</DTS:Property>
</DTS:Property>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible<sup>*</sup>. For pre-2012 packages and 2012/2014 packages using the package deployment model, logging involves modifying the package itself.

If you are handy with .NET, you can look at how to turn on/off logging via code in my post on [Replicate tables with SSIS EzAPI](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2012/03/replicate-tables-with-ssis-ezapi.html) (no need to download the EzAPI library for this)

Relevant code bits here

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Enable logging
// Add log provider and such
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.logproviders.add.aspx
// ProgID: DTS.LogProviderSQLServer.2
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
DTSEventColumnFilter eventFilter = new DTSEventColumnFilter();
eventFilter.Computer = true;
eventFilter.DataBytes = true;
eventFilter.ExecutionID = true;
eventFilter.MessageText = true;
eventFilter.Operator = true;
eventFilter.SourceID = true;
eventFilter.SourceName = true;

p.LoggingMode = DTSLoggingMode.Enabled;

// Define the events we care about
string[] notableEvents = new string[] { "OnError", "OnInformation", "OnPostExecute", "OnPreExecute", "OnWarning", "OnTaskFailed" };

// Add and configure the sql log provider
LogProvider provider = p.LogProviders.Add("DTS.LogProviderSQLServer.2");

provider.ConfigString = loggingCM.Name;
provider.Name = "SSIS log provider for SQL Server";
provider.Description = "Writes log entries for events to a SQL Server database";
p.LoggingOptions.SelectedLogProviders.Add(provider);

LoggingOptions options = p.LoggingOptions;
// load up the events we care about
options.EventFilter = notableEvents;
options.EventFilterKind = DTSEventFilterKind.Inclusion;

// configure the specifics of how an event should be logged
foreach (string item in notableEvents)
{
    options.SetColumnFilter(item, eventFilter);
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Depending on your organization's tolerance for open source products, [dtLoggedExec](http://dtloggedexec.codeplex.com/)